# How to determine (at runtime) if a variable is annotated as deprecated?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, deprecated

This code can check whether a **class** is deprecated or not

`@Deprecated`
`public class`<s>`RetentionPolicyExample`</s>`{`

```
             public static void main(String[] args){  
                 boolean isDeprecated=false;             
                 if(RetentionPolicyExample.class.getAnnotations().length>0){  
                     isDeprecated= RetentionPolicyExample.class  
                                   .getAnnotations()[0].toString()
                                   .contains("Deprecated");  
                 }  
                 System.out.println("is deprecated:"+ isDeprecated);             
             }  
      }
```

**But, how can be checked if any variable is annotated as deprecated?**

`@Deprecated`
`String`<s>`variable;`</s>

Comment: be careful with `.getAnnotations()[0]` as a class might have more than 1 annotation

Comment: @Hernán, do you have a class and you want to check if it has at least one field, which is marked as @Deprecated?

Comment: Retrieve the fields of the class - then use `Field::getAnnotations`?

Comment: @VadymPechenoha I was thinking in specific variables check, but what you said could be checking every field, is ok too

Comment: @assylias thanks, testing Field class now as seen also in answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

Field[] fields = RetentionPolicyExample.class // Get the class
                .getDeclaredFields(); // Get its fields

boolean isAnyDeprecated = Stream.of(fields) // Iterate over fields
                // If it is deprecated, this gets the annotation.
                // Else, null
                .map(field -> field.getAnnotation(Deprecated.class))
                .anyMatch(x -> x != null); // Is there a deprecated annotation somewhere?
```

Comment: It works just fine for me. Did you recompile the class after you changed the `@Deprecated` annotations? Did you make sure *no* fields were `@Deprecated` when you tested for `false`?

Answer (score 2):

You are checking the `Class` annotations. The reflection API's also give you access to `Field` and `Method` annotations.

See

- Class.getFields() and Class.getDeclaredFields()
- Class.getMethods() and Class.getDeclaredMethods()
- Class.getSuperClass()

A couple of problems with your implementation

1. You are only checking `getAnnotations[0]` when there might be more than one annotation
2. You are testing `toString().contains("Deprecated")` when you should check `.equals(Deprecated.class)`
3. You could use `.getAnnotation(Deprecated.class)`